# How can I draw Map in Android Activity?

Tags: android

I want to Draw a map view in android where states are clickable. Depending on the click the state information will be updated. How can i achieve this? Is there any library that i can use?[image]

Comment: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: `Is there any library that i can use` asking for a library is off-topic

Comment: that does not matter

Comment: @GowthamanM I want the Only single Country to be shown in the Map. (Specifically India) And on clicking a state, entire state will be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make each state have unique color, you can check the pixel color on the clicked point:

```
public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent ev) 
{

    final int action = ev.getAction();

    final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
    final int evY = (int) ev.getY();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
           break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
           ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById (YOUR_IMG_DRAWABLE);
           img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
           Bitmap imgbmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache()); 
           img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

           int pxl = imgbmp.getPixel(evX, evY);

           int redComponent = Color.red(pxl);
           int greenComponent = Color.green(pxl);
           int blueComponent = Color.blue(pxl);

           break;
    }

}
```

And then depending on the color, check which state was clicked, and do whatever you need.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. How do i draw map boundries? and Fill color in the states?

Comment: You can use a single bitmap with pre-drawn everything.